# $C_o= \{(x_n):x_n \in R, x_n \rightarrow 0 \}$ and $ M=\{(x_n):x_n \in C_0,~~ x_1+ x_2+...+x_{10}=0\}$ then dimension of $(\frac{C_0}{M})$ is equal to

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C_o= \{(x_n):x_n \in R, x_n \rightarrow 0 \}$ and $ M=\{(x_n):x_n \in C_0,~~ x_1+ x_2+...+x_{10}=0\}$ then dimension of $(\frac{C_0}{M})$ is equal to

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried? Do you have any guess as to what the answer should be?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A very quick approach is to use the first isomorphism theorem.  That is, if there is a space $Y$ an onto map $\phi: C_0 \to Y$ for which $\ker \phi = M$, then we must have
$$
\frac{C_0}{M} \cong Y
$$

Comment: I guess the answer should be $1$

Comment: Good guess. Can you prove that this is the answer now?